# When to use DatePickerDialog over a DatePicker in a DialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-dialogfragment, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

When should I use say a DatePickerDialog over a DatePicker widget inflated in a DialogFragment? I've always done it the second way and have no idea when/how to use the first method. The same question applies to other picker widgets like TimePicker and TimePickerDialog as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Difference between `DatePickerDialog` and `DatePicker`

- `DatePicker` - It is a Control by itself.
- `DatePickerDialog` - It is a dialog with a date picker

When should I use ?

1. Use `DatePicker` *control* in your activity layout (in case you have enough space)
2. Use the `DatePickerDialog` when you don't have enough space and/or if you want to open the date *dialog* in a separate view.

As per the doc, `DatePickerDialog` is a

> A simple dialog containing an DatePicker.

PS. In my experience, I would avoid using it the `DatePicker` in the activity layout straight away because of space constraints. Consider devices like nexus 4 when you use them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you explain what you mean by space constraints? Do you mean the size of the device? And why does that play a part in choosing which to use?

Comment: Yes. That is my personal experience. What I actually meant was, all date pickers require a scroll view when you have other controls in the activity. When you want the users focus on the date picker alone, you might want to use it in a dialog.